# BitBucket commands for initial upload don't work on windows?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Created a repository under bitbucket. Then I created a directory and a couple of files.

I initialized the directory:

```
myname@mybox ~/AndroidStudioProjects/test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/myname/AndroidStudioProjects/test/.git/
```

And then I copy pasted the command lines directly from the bitbucket website (obfuscating account names):

```
myname@mybox ~/AndroidStudioProjects/test (master)
$ git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test98.git

myname@mybox ~/AndroidStudioProjects/test (master)
$ git push -u origin --all
Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org':
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

This is with the git-bash shell, if that makes any difference.

Are the bitbucket-supplied git commands not correct? Are they not correct for git-bash under windows? Are they incomplete and there's some step I missed?

Comment: Did you first add and commit? Run.. git add . and then git commit -m 'initial commit' before pushing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to upload a few files in a specified remote repository. To do this you use the following set of commands:

- git init
- git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/test98.git
- git add -A
- git commit -m"your commit message here"
- git push -u origin --all

Comment: Yes. Those steps don't seem to be there in the BitBucket instructions but turns out that's what I had to do.